# playframework 1.2 sample application throws 505 when deployed to google-appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework

I created a sample application in playframework 1.2 and tried to deploy it to google-appengine, the deployment showed no issues. but when I hit my application, it shows a 505 error.

when I checked the logs, I found that its throwing an error, and coming to the funny part, it shows a servlet exception, huhh! play is totally out of servlet/jsp world. how come it throws servlet exception?

The full stack trace is

> Could not instantiate listener play.server.ServletWrapper
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.server.ServletWrapper  at
>   com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-b8b4d374cb7c1344(Request.java)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)    at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1101)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>
> W 2012-06-06 14:32:23.044
>
> EXCEPTION  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   play.server.ServletWrapper    at
>   com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-b8b4d374cb7c1344(Request.java)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)    at
>   org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)     at
>   org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>
> E 2012-06-06 14:32:23.045
>
> javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: play.server.ServletWrapper    at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>
> W 2012-06-06 14:32:23.092
>
> Failed startup of context
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@15e00b7{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~play-gae2/1.359439975758049816}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>
> C 2012-06-06 14:32:23.093
>
> Uncaught exception from servlet javax.servlet.UnavailableException:
>   Initialization failed.    at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:211)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Answer (score 0):

Although Play doesn't use Servlets, to make Play work in J2EE containers, including GAE, play uses a Servlet wrapper to route requests from the J2EE container into the Play code.

From the exception you are getting, it looks like this Play servlet wrapper is not available. Are you deploying it using the GAE module within Play? This should create a WAR file and upload it directly to GAE for you. This should ensure that everything that is required is correctly copied across.

Comment: thats how I am doing it. it creates a war in /tmp directory and uploads it to appengine.

Comment: do you have the right GAE SDK, Play only supports 1.4...also what platform are you running on? I have had trouble using windows, but with mac and linux it works pretty well.

Comment: ya I know that it supports only 1.4 sdk and I am doing it in ubuntu.